Apache Spark: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError for software.amazon.awssdk.transfer.s3.progress.TransferListener when reading CSV from S3
I am trying to read a CSV file from S3 using Apache Spark, but I encounter the following error:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: software/amazon/awssdk/transfer/s3/progress/TransferListener
  at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
  at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
  at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByNameOrNull(Configuration.java:2625)
  ...

These are the jars I'm using:
C:/spark/jars/iceberg-spark-runtime-3.5_2.12-1.7.1.jar,
C:/spark/jars/hadoop-aws-3.4.0.jar,
C:/spark/jars/aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.999.jar,
C:/spark/jars/aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.999.jar,
C:/spark/jars/aws-sdk-core-2.17.99.jar,
C:/spark/jars/aws-sdk-s3-2.17.99.jar
Using only AWS SDK v1 (aws-java-sdk-core and aws-java-sdk-s3) causes authentication errors.
Using only AWS SDK v2 (aws-sdk-core and aws-sdk-s3) results in missing TransferListener.
Combining v1 and v2 jars in the spark-shell command, I'm still getting the same NoClassDefFoundError.

Do not use both AWS SDK v2 and v1 at the same time

You should use spark.jars.packages config variable in the codebase where you are using these functions, not directly modifying the global Spark classpath.

Thanks for pitching in to help find the solution,
spark-shell --packages org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.4.0,software.amazon.awssdk:sdk-core:2.20.32,software.amazon.awssdk:s3:2.20.32,org.apache.iceberg:iceberg-spark-runtime-3.5_2.12:1.7.1 this however is storing in central. i minimized the v1 and v2 conflicts,

but couldnt get rid of this new exception  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: software/amazon/awssdk/awscore/exception/AwsServiceException
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1021)
at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:800)
im stuck into this for some time bro :->,  can we look into this

You need to add aws-core dependency as well, but you probably shouldn't. The hadoop-aws one has everything you need and it uses AWS SDK v1. If you have auth errors, that is a completely separate problem and the dependencies are correct

i have tried to run do it without aws-core by running on this spark-shell --packages org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.4.0,org.apache.iceberg:iceberg-spark-runtime-3.5_2.12:1.7.1... in my case i still had aws exception. also with aws core again different version spark-shell --packages org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.4.0,org.apache.iceberg:iceberg-spark-runtime-3.5_2.12:1.7.1,software.amazon.awssdk:sdk-core:2.17.192,software.amazon.awssdk:s3:2.17.192,software.amazon.awssdk:auth:2.17.192. im really struggling with this as a intern more than 1week same issue. earlier i tried helm charts they avoided

im missing something related to dependency

@KrishnaBasutkar You cannot add both AWS SDK 1.x (within hadoop-aws) and 2.x (external packages). As stated, as "AWS Exception" has nothing to do with the packages you're loading, and that needs fixed in your Hadoop XML files in SPARK_HOME/conf or HADOOP_HOME/conf

hey, i followed same and tried to do it and get back to you but kind of ran into something. before trying this again have used sbt to just read, i wish to start a spark so that i can create into iceberg tables and manage metadata. can we connect over gmeet for 15mins pls i request you theres no better help ik where you come from and its only about solutions here but there is no much progress))

I have no experience with Iceberg. I cannot help with this, and I dont see it as much an improvement over Spark Connect for your use-case. You'd be better converting the CSV to Parquert first.

yes, i have converted its in s3 bucket. i have downgraded to hadoop 3.2.3 to have hadoop aws and spark iceberg in v1. in this case i get java.io.IOException: From option fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.auth.IAMInstanceCredentialsProvider not found which is trying to get v2 i dont know how. i was looking to get the correct exact packages right to make other things work))

can you quickly suggest which --packages to run, im trying to configure the best aswell

hey, im actively working on config your little suggestion would be very much appreciated

hello can you pls check once. i have downgraded to hadoop 3.2.3 and using hadoop aws and spark iceberg for v1. but havng missing class for fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.auth.IAMInstanceCredentialsProvider

Since you have accepted the answer already, please make a new post for new errors. And you don't need Iceberg to use S3, so try to focus on one dependency at a time
